# Docker command for activating docker.service

Tags: docker

I am trying to run `systemctl status docker` command and it shows me the error:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2016-07-18 14:12:36 EEST; 11min ago

Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 11919 ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// $DOCKER_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 11919 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

I would like to know if is there any command for activating Docker services?

Comment: Have you tried restarting it (`sudo systemctl start docker`)?  You'll have to run `status` again to see what happened, it will probably contain a record of both attempts -- if not check the PID against the one you already have to make sure it actually tried.  I'm not a user so I don't know, but I would assume docker requires some configuration to do anything meaningful, so if you have not set it up then perhaps that is the reason.  You could also check `sudo grep docker /var/log/syslog` to see if there is any more information.

Comment: Yes I tried to restart it and it shows this error:  Job for docker.service failed. See 'systemctl status docker.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details. I am sorry cause I am new to Linux and I am stuck with this error now.

Comment: If you are new to linux you are presumably new to Docker, so perhaps you should include details about what you were *expecting* to happen.  If you had no idea what was going to happen, then perhaps this is what is supposed to happen given whatever it is you are (not) trying to do...

Comment: Could you let us know how you installed Docker on your Raspberry Pi? And what is the output of `journalctl -xn` as it was suggested to you.